How to add widgets to a layout without affecting already added widgets in the layout
I am trying to add  certain number of buttons to a box layout while giving them a text from lines of a file opened as self.pp. However what's I want is that on click of any button the corresponding pdf file is opened through the function opener but I later discovered that no matter which button I pressed, the file opened corresponds to the last item in self.pp which makes me think that widgets are somehow affected by a newly added one
Here's the code
class Cours(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.pp=open("cours_n1.txt","r")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation="vertical"
        self.spacing = dp(5)
        self.pos_hint={"top":1}
        for i,line in enumerate(self.pp.readlines()):
            b=Button(text=line,size_hint=(.8,None),pos_hint={"x":.1},height=(dp(40)),on_press=lambda x:self.opener(line))
            self.add_widget(b)
    def opener(self,line):
        u = "C:\myown\computer\Assassin simulate" + line
        u = u.rstrip('\n')
        os.startfile(u)


The lambda function is not evaluated until the Button is pressed, so the line parameter will always be the last value of line. The fix is to create a temporary parameter that takes the current value of line and uses that in the lambda. Like this:
b=Button(text=line,size_hint=(.8,None),pos_hint={"x":.1},height=(dp(40)),on_press=lambda x, ln=line:self.opener(ln))


Ok thanks it worked perfectly
